# random open ports on nmap scan

Tags: networking, port, nmap

My machine has the IP address 192.168.1.50 . When i do the following nmap scan `nmap -p- -sT -Pn 192.168.1.50` from the same machine, i get at each scan some random open ports. And these random open ports are different with every scan.

What is happening, did some one hack me and left a back port or something like that (though, the back port need to be fix i guess), if it isn't the case, can someone explain to me this mysterious behaving

PS : When i scan the same machine from another one, with the same scan, nmap tells me that all the port are closed.

PS : I use Ubuntu 15.10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" of the Linux kernel that allows a socket to connect to itself when the destination port is the same as the ephemeral port that the kernel chooses for the socket. Nmap versions 6.40 to 6.47 were missing a check for this specific case, so self-connections show up randomly in high-numbered ports. Upgrade to a newer Nmap version (7.01 was released in December 2016) to fix this problem and benefit from a lot of new features.

(Previously answered on StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506699/nmap-shows-random-open-ports-on-localhost-for-a-fraction-of-a-second)

Answer (score 0):

Your machine uses ephemeral ports to connect to other machines in a client-server model.  For example, if you're on Stack Exchange, you'll be connecting to the server on port 80, but the port your computer uses will be a random high port.

If you really want to see how nmap interprets the data, run a netstat in your terminal window alongside the nmap scan.

Also, **one way** to know if you're getting hacked is to close your browser so you have as few established connections as possible, run a netstat, and do a whois query on the foreign addresses.